# After removing <tr> from table with jquery, wrong functions are called on click events for buttons in other rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

The setup is the following:
each row in the table describes an item from database, according to a specific form. Each `<td>` element represents a value of a form element. The first `<td>` element in each row is a button which on click is supposed to send to the server the `item_id` held in its (the button's) row and after the server returns success, the row containing the id that was sent is supposed to be removed.

What actually happens, is that after I remove some row, later in the onclick function in other rows the id is the one of the removed row. For example if I have:

```
<tr id=1></tr>
<tr id=2></tr>
```

Jquery code used to remove rows:
(itemId is changed in loop...)

```
var num = eval($("#oldnum").val()) + 2;
for (var i=2; i < num; i++ ){
//      var remElem = $('#items tbody tr:nth-child('+i+') img[name="remitem"]');
        var remElem = $('#remitem'+(i-2));
        var row = $('#items tbody tr:nth-child('+i+')');
        var itemId = $(row).attr('id').split("_");
        //id of a row is item_actualId, we want the actualId
        itemId = itemId[1];
        $(remElem).click(function(){
            removeExistingItem(itemId);
        });
}
...
function removeExistingItem(itemId){
    var answer = confirm("האם ברצונך למחוק את  הפריט?");
    if (!answer){
        return;
    }
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/po/removeitem", dataType: "json",
        data: {id: itemId, format: "json"}, success: function(){
            $('#items tr[id="item_'+itemId+'"]').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Any help is welcomed...

Comment: Can you show the handler being set up?  First thought is that you're using the index of the table row and not a real ID, so it makes sense that after removing one the index is still there (the one beneath it just got moved up.)

Comment: Please show how you're assigning the value to `itemId` in the `click` handler

Comment: Also, the HTML you posted shows numeric IDs (which aren't valid in HTML4), but your code suggests IDs that look like `item_1`.

Comment: I added the code assigning value to itemId.

Comment: @patrick dw thats exactly how the look - item_1, item_12

The problem figured to be that in all elements the removeExistingItem was called with the same value - I suppose that the value of itemId in the anonymous function wasn't evaluated until calling those functions, rather somehow some form of reference to the itemId variable was kept. If this is so the it makes perfect sense since then all the functions evaluate itemId to its assigned value. Can someone confirm my conclusion?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can simplify this by simply maintaining your reference:

```
$(remElement).click(function()
{
    var currentObj = this;

    $.ajax({
       url: 'myUrl',
       data: { myData: 'Value1' },
       success: function()
       {
           $(currentObj).parent().parent().remove();
       }
    });
});
```

Simply maintain a reference to your current object, and then walk up the tree to find it's parent row and remove that.

Comment: his looks much cleaner to me, though i might change the removal line to use .closest('tr') since chaining .parent() functions can get convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try doing: (using the id selector)

```
$('#item_'+itemId).remove();
```